# VBA msgbox to be a result of address(es) of (cells) if the condition fails

Tags: vba, excel

A macro checks for compliance of multiple conditions and returns a msgbox with general message. The issue is that the message is NOT specific and it is repeated a lot of times as there is a loop to check criteria. If there a way to incorporate a msgbox which would to be a result of address(es) of (cells) if the condition fails.

```
Sub CheckFundsInISAccounts()

'Version 9 change.

    Dim c As Range
    Dim lstRng As Range
    Dim LastRow As Integer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Worksheets("DataFile").Activate
    Range("U2").Activate

    LastRow = Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).row

    Set lstRng = Range("U2", Range("U65536").End(xlUp))

    For Each c In lstRng
        If c.Value > 29999 _
        And (c.Offset(0, -2).Value = 10 _
        Or c.Offset(0, -2).Value = 11 _
        Or c.Offset(0, -2).Value = 12 _
        Or c.Offset(0, -2).Value = 20 _
        Or c.Offset(0, -2).Value = 45 _
        Or c.Offset(0, -2).Value = 60 _
        Or c.Offset(0, -2).Value = 70) Then
            c.Offset(1, 0).Select

        Else
            'A macro checks for compliance of multiple conditions and returns a msgbox with    
            'general message.
            'The issue is that the message is NOT specific and it is repeated a lot of times as 
            'there is a loop to check criteria.
            'If there a way to incorporate a msgbox which would to be a result of address(es) of 
            'cells if the condition fails.

            MsgBox ("NOT every IS account has a Fund assigned to it. Double-check it")            
        End If
    Next c

    Columns("A:W").Select
    Selection.EntireColumn.AutoFit

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: in your Else statement, build up a string of addresses that fail the condition and after your loop, generate a msgbox that returns a message along w/ the string.

Comment: Could you provide me with an example line? Thank you

Comment: My solution would be quite similar to @Thinkingcap, I'd just use that one...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple Changes:

The conditions in OR moved to `Case`

`.Address` to capture the cell addresses

```
Sub CheckFundsInISAccounts()
'Version 9 change.
Dim c As Range
Dim lstRng As Range
Dim LastRow As Integer
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Worksheets("DataFile").Activate
Range("U2").Select
Debug.Print Rows.Count
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set lstRng = Range("U2", Range("U65536").End(xlUp))
Dim MyAdd As String

For Each c In lstRng
    If c.Value > 29999 Then
        Select Case (c.Offset(0, -2).Value)
        Case 10, 11, 12, 20, 45, 60, 70
            c.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Case Else
          'MyAdd = MyAdd & c.Offset(0, -2).Address & vbCrLf
          c.Offset(0, -2).Value = "I am not one of Your Values"
         End Select

    Else
     MyAdd = MyAdd & c.Address & vbCrLf
     c.Value = "I am not Greater Than 29999"
    End If

Next c
'MsgBox ("Error Addresses are:" & vbCrLf & MyAdd)
Columns("A:W").Select
Selection.EntireColumn.AutoFit

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for a valuable answer. Actually I think a better approach would be to eliminate to eliminate fund # rather than asking user to check message and make appropriate changes.  in cell.Offset(0,-2).Value = :"". So I added:  Else  c.Offset(0, -2).Value = "" but it doesn't capture an error :  there is an IS account (>29999) but Fund is empty. Any thoughts?

Comment: There are Two Else Parts `I)When C.Value>29999 and C.offset(0,-2) value not in (10,11,20...)` `II)C.value<29999` The one you are referring to is `case I`